# What is this Illegal argument(s) to subplot: (15, 2)?

Tags: python, valueerror

I have an error. It is this `ValueError: Illegal argument(s) to subplot: (15, 2)` from this code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplot(15, 2, figsize=(10, 20))
mglignant = canner.data[cancer.target == 0]
benign = cancer.data[cancer.target == 1]
    
ax = axes.ravel()

for i in range(30):
    _, bins = np.histogram(cancer.data[:, i], bins=50)
    ax[i].hist(malignant[:, i], bins=bins, color=mglearn.cm3(0), alpha=.5)
    ax[i].hist(benign[:, i], bins=bins, color=mglearn.cm3(2), alpha=.5)
    ax[i].set_title(cancer.feature_names[i])
    ax[i].set_yticks(())
ax[0].set_xlabel("Characteristic size")
ax[0].set_ylabel("frequency")
ax[0].legend(["malignity", "positivity"], loc="best")
fig.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use either of these: (pay attention to the `s` at the end)

```
plt.subplots(15, 2, figsize=(10, 20))
```

or

```
plt.subplot(15, 2, 1)
```